# Where does the label "ruamel" come from in regards to ruamel.* pypi packages?

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

Where does the label "ruamel" come from in regards to ruamel.* pypi packages?

All of my google searches are returning documentation for ruamel.yaml, but there are other packages like ruamel.ordereddict, ruamel.base, and so forth. I understand that ruamel is technically just a package namespace, but I was curious if this is a namespace that builds up to some cohesive set of tools and/or product, or is it merely a namespace/brand for anthon's (the author's) code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name Ruamel, is the name of a company¹. It doesn't really have a meaning, but there is a street 'Rua mel' (honey-road?) somewhere in Portugal.

As the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) indicates: "Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!".
Namespaces were necessary to prevent clashes between company internal packages (there are over 150 of those) and packages on PyPi. Most `ruamel.` packages that are in the public domain were originally company internal packages.
[image]

The namespace allows e.g. to have a package that wraps the standard library
`pathlib` with some extra functionality (and backwards compatibility for Python 2) and have it name `ruamel.std.pathlib`

Note that user anthon is the maintainer of ruamel.yaml:
[image]

---

¹ <sub>That name was chosen based on the combined and mixed initials of the two children of Ruamel's founder.</sub>